# How to return entire mysql table with php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$values = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$values[] = array($row['tried']);
}
return $values;
```

That only returns the word array when being called as a webservice. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You are not echoing anything here, so this is not the code where the problem is. You probably need to show the full code

Comment: Decide what format you want it in (HTML, XML, json, serialized, comma separated, etc.),and use that.

Comment: Please explain what kind of web services you're using.  Are you using a library?  What is the MIME type?

Comment: what is the structure of your data? what do you expect from the column 'tried'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning the word 'array', it's telling you that what is being returned is an array.

To see what is in the array, use either `var_dump($values);` or `print_r($values);`.  The only difference is the format of the display.

In addition, I don't believe you need to declare array in your assignment to `$values`.

```
$values[] = $row['tried'];
```

should work.  `$values` will still be an array.

Comment: thanks for this worked perfectly...now just need to figure out this " content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'" error when it returns $values

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try changing the last line to: `return json_encode($values);`. It should at least let you see what you're doing (and may even be usable, depending on situation).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to SELECT * if you are only using one column.  Just SELECT that column.

If it is printing out array, you are probably calling

```
echo $values;
```

This is not going to work.  There are many solutions to see what you want, e.g.

```
foreach ($values as $val) { echo $val; }
```